# Deriving exact solutions to trig functions (eg, $\cos\frac\pi3=\frac12$)?

Tags: trigonometry

There are a few points around the unit circle that are not multiples of arc length $\frac{\pi}{2}$ that have neat exact solutions for the trig functions.  For example:

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2} \qquad\text{or}\qquad\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and so on.

> Is there any way to derive these results?

That is, how can you show (perhaps through "mechanical" proof) that $\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: For  $ \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ $ and $ \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ $ , divide an equilateral triangle into two right triangles.  A right isosceles triangle has two equal angles of $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ . $  Pretty much any book on trigonometry will show how the trig values are obtained.

Comment: @boojum: Yeah I was thinking about that too.  That's kind of using "geometric" reasoning.  I was trying to grasp for a more algebraic kind of answer.  I probably don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I consider the geometric reasoning a "mechanical" proof.  You could arrive at the trig values starting from $ \ m \ = \ \tan \theta \ , $ with $ \ m \ $ being the slope of a line through the origin and $ \ \theta \ $ being the angle the line makes to the $ \ x-$ axis and use a unit hypotenuse to write equations to find the other trig values.  ( $ \ x^2 \ + \ x^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ for the right isosceles triangle with unit hypotenuse, and $ \ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ x^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ for the divided equilateral triangle.  But this is what you do for the geometric construction anyway.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry#:~:text=In%20the%20early%209th%20century,a%20pioneer%20in%20spherical%20trigonometry. Does this help?

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: You could also get them from suitable use of the double- and triple-angle formulas applied against the sine and cosine of $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ , but any of these more sophisticated methods are pretty roundabout ways to get to a simple result (although it's nice to see that they all agree).